# Call mixin if variable is defined

Tags: css, less, lessphp

I try to use mixin guards with `when` condition, but during compiling I get the following error:

> .mixin is undefined

```
.mixin (@color) when (isstring(@color)) {
  //some code
}

.mixin(#008000);
```

When I remove the `when` condition it works. Whats the problem here?

---

The problem is that we have variables inside our less-files which are defined in one compile-process. But during another compile-process this variables are not defined because we need a little bit dynamic here.

So I have to check if the variable is defined. When I try it over

```
$variables = [
   'testColor' => '#fff111',
];
$lessc->setVariables($variables);
$cachedCompile = $lessc->cachedCompile($publicPath .   $inputFile);
```

and

```
.mixin (@color:none) when (iscolor(@color)) {
   color: #fff;
}

.mixin(@testColor);
```

Everything works. But when I remove the `testColor` variable in the variable-array it crashes because it isn't defined.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with how you have defined the mixin and you should certainly not be getting that error. You can check on lesstester.com. Other than that, using `isstring()` on a color would mean that the mixin would not output anything because the condition fails.

Comment: You are also getting error with `when( @color = '')`?

Comment: Yes, the main problem what i try to fix over a mixin guard is to check if a variable is defined or not. Is there another way to do this in less?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be because you are trying to pass a variable (`@testColor`) that does not exist as a parameter to the mixin. Try by adding the below line to the very top of your Less file.

```
@testColor: none;
```

Since Less does lazy loading of variables, if there is a value set during compilation that should overwrite the `none`. If no variable is set during compilation the above line would still mean that the variable is defined and has some default value.

---

There is no direct `isnull` or `isnotnull` type of function in Less. However, you can mimick the behavior by assigning a default value to the mixin.

In the below sample, we assign the default value as `none` which is not a color and hence when the `iscolor(@color)` condition is checked it would fail and the mixin would not produce any output.

I have also added a `not` condition below for you to see the difference.

```css
.mixin (@color:none) when (iscolor(@color)) {
  //some code
  color: is defined;
}
.mixin (@color:none) when not (iscolor(@color)) {
  //some code
  color: is not defined;
}

#output1{
  .mixin();
}
#output2{
  .mixin(#ff0000);
}
#output3{
  .mixin(abcd);
}
```